I keep getting a blank command line window when I open Blender


This has been ongoing since yesterday I have deleted all my Blender versions, uninstalled, re-downloaded them and it still is happening.
I keep getting this blank command line window
At first it had errors referring to my file location.
The initial error pointed to the Python folder.
Right now I only use the portable version.
I'm always using more than one version.
I deleted the user preference file from both versions to do a factory reset and I'm still getting this same blank window.

We need to see a screenshot of the errors.

That is a pretty old version of Blender, 2.76 is from back in 2015, 9 years old. Wouldn't be surprised if it did not run in modern OSs well. Any reason for using such outdated versions? Also back then it was pretty normal for Blender to keep an open command line at all times while running

If you look carefully at the top of the first image that is blender 4.2.  The reason for using the older version is because of a workflow that requires it.  The screenshots are from two different versions of blender.

The found bundled python is what I don't get.  I'm not worried about the failed to set part of the message.  I still have not found an answer for that bundled python message.  I saw on a post someone linked a .py file they said to add it to the directory, but I'm nervous about putting someone who I don't know file on my computer.
